# MarkLogic v1/transactions create by REST API

Tags: rest, transactions, marklogic

I have been trying to create a transaction via the MarkLogic REST API (/v1/transactions) using the Developer guidance here: https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/transactions

When I try to call the transaction REST service to create a new transaction (I am using CURL), then I receive the following HTTP Response:

```
curl -X POST -d "" -i --anyauth --user user:password http://localhost:7010/v1/transactions

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="public", ...
Content-type: application/xml
Server: MarkLogic
Content-Length: 211
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-type: application/xml
Server: MarkLogic
Content-Length: 316
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

<rapi:error xmlns:rapi="http://marklogic.com/rest-api">
  <rapi:status-code>400</rapi:status-code><rapi:status>Bad Request</rapi:status>
  <rapi:message-code>REST-INVALIDPARAM</rapi:message-code>
  <rapi:message>REST-INVALIDPARAM: (err:FOER0000) Invalid parameter: could not parse transaction id </rapi:message>
</rapi:error>
```

Interestingly, when I use POSTMAN within Chrome, I can create the transaction, but the response is different to that expected (It response with **200** status and with XML detailing the transaction, rather than a **303** response and the "Location" header set to the transaction ID).

Can anyone help me explain why this CURL statement is failing?

Cheers

Comment: The 200 vs 303 might be your client following a redirect automatically. Sometimes it's less confusing to disable that in the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a `curl` "**convenience**" and not your request.

When you don't specify the Content-Type for a **POST**, `curl` "helpfully" defaults the **Content-Type** to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

The `REST API` processes a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` `POST` as a `GET` because there is no payload, only parameters, which is why it looks like a bad request.

Try the same `curl` command but adding a `-H 'Content-Type: text/plain'` argument.

Hoping that helps

Comment: Cheers, that worked.  Someone has put a comment on the Developer documentation as well so others should benefit from this advice.  Thanks again. :)