# Marklogic v1/transactions create by REST API : error

Tags: marklogic

I am getting the below error while calling the below Rest service in SOAPUI tool  :

```
http://localhost:7060/v1/transactions 

Error : 
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: MarkLogic
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=public
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 104
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

{"errorResponse":   {"statusCode":401,
   "status":"Unauthorized",
   "message":"401 Unauthorized"
  }
}
```

After going through the below link I think its something related to Content-Type, I tried with text/plain but its still not working, Any help around it ?

[MarkLogic v1/transactions create by REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084315/marklogic-v1-transactions-create-by-rest-api)

Comment: It looks like the user or password is not correct.  Are you using POST?  Have you tried other REST clients such as curl?

Comment: @ehennum All other REST operations are working fine..when I tried the same request with Post man its working fine, but response received in postman is with Status Code 200 instead of 303 as indicated in documentation & response body is <rapi:transaction-id>7341689848759709324</rapi:transaction-id>

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the authentication setting in the MarkLogic REST API server in admin console to "digestbasic" and use HTTP Basic Auth ("Basic {TOKEN}") in your REST client to ensure that your login credentials in the `Authorization` header are correct.